# PHPWord long text new line tab

Tags: php, html, phpword

Assume I have this dynamic long text in table and it has two tab at the beginning :

```
$table->addCell(2000,$cellTelegram)
      ->addText("\t\tABCDEFASDASDASDASDASDASDAS (auto line break) DASDASDASDASDASDASDsASDASD");
```

[image: The result]

[image: What I want to achieve]

The problem is, the text after auto line break is not tabbed like the first line.

How can I make the second line after auto line break have the same tab as the first line?

Comment: Did you see [this doc](https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/elements.html#breaks)?

Comment: yes, the problem is actually my text is dynamic in length, so i can't just text break at some point

Comment: Look at [this](https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/elements.html#texts) and [this](https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/styles.html#paragraph-style) doc.

Comment: Okay, thank you sir, somehow i managed to do it